LEFT JOIN en LinQ presenta error Timeout
Cordial saludo. En la actualidad estamos realizando un LEFT JOIN dentro de un metodo con el animo de identificar los datos validas de aquellos que no lo son. En nuestra logica, un dato valido es aquel que encuentra valores que no son NULL en la otra tabla, osea aquellos que tienen relacion en ambas tablas y un valor NoValido es aquel que es NULL al realizar la operacion del LEFT JOIN. Este es el metodo:
[HttpGet("/Llantas/Mantenimientos/Equipos/Revisar", Name = "GetLlantasMantenimientosEquiposRevisar")]
    public List<TemGeneMttoPrevObras> GetLlantasMantenimientosEquiposRevisar()
    {
        try
        {
            var q = from a in context.GeneMttoPrev
                    // 2024-07-09: Join entre dos tablas (tabla a y tabla b1).
                    join b1 in context.LlanHistoria on
                            a.equipo
                        equals
                            b1.equipo
                        into GrupoB
                    // 2024-07-09: Esto lo hago para que que sean LEFT JOIN.
                    from b in GrupoB.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new TemGeneMttoPrevObras
                    {
                        Registro = a.Registro,
                        equipo = a.equipo,
                        bodega = a.bodega,
                        codigo_mantenimiento = a.codigo_mantenimiento,
                        ciclo = a.ciclo,
                        frecuencia_Mantenimiento = a.frecuencia_Mantenimiento,
                        unidad_frecuencia = a.unidad_frecuencia,
                        fecha_estimada = a.fecha_estimada,
                        fecha_mantenimiento = a.fecha_mantenimiento,
                        horometro_estimado = a.horometro_estimado,
                        horometro_mantenimiento = a.horometro_mantenimiento,
                        horometro_final = a.horometro_final,
                        resultado_muestreo = a.resultado_muestreo,
                        emp = a.emp,
                        // 2024-07-08: Debido a que en la clase o mejor dicho en C# no esposible tener
                        // datos tipo DateTime como null, se procede a modificar el dato.
                        FechaInsert = new DateTime(1900, 01, 01),
                        // 2024-07-09: Para no crear una clase para este metodo se aprovecha uno ya creado pero
                        // se inhabilitan el campo Obra, el cual se calcula realmente en otro metodo.
                        Obra = "NoAplica",
                        // 2024-06-21: Se valida si hay registros en la tabla indicada.
                        Estado = b == null ? "NoAplica" : "Aplica"
                    };
            return q.ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return TemGeneMttoPrevObrasExcepcion;
        }
    }

Al ejecutar el metodo, notamos que tarda mucho en entregar datos y posterior a ello, en ocasiones nos entrega errores del tipo TIMEOUT.
Debido a que unas veces genera el error TIMEOUT y otras nos, nos lleva a entender que no seria muy confiable tener un metodo de este tipo que puede hacer que el aplicativo no funcione correctamente.
Tratando de reproducir el error en un aplicativo donde podemos ejecutar codigo LinQ como si estuvieramos en SQL Server y poder ver las tablas que estos generan, ejecutamos el siguiente codigo en LINQPad 7:
from a in GeneMttoPrev
                    // 2024-07-09: Join entre dos tablas (tabla a y tabla b1).
                    join b1 in LlanHistoria on
                            a.equipo
                        equals
                            b1.equipo
                        into GrupoB
                    // 2024-07-09: Esto lo hago para que que sean LEFT JOIN.
                    from b in GrupoB.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new 
                    {
                        Registro = a.Registro,
                        equipo = a.equipo,
                        bodega = a.bodega,
                        codigo_mantenimiento = a.codigo_mantenimiento,
                        ciclo = a.ciclo,
                        frecuencia_Mantenimiento = a.frecuencia_Mantenimiento,
                        unidad_frecuencia = a.unidad_frecuencia,
                        fecha_estimada = a.fecha_estimada,
                        fecha_mantenimiento = a.fecha_mantenimiento,
                        horometro_estimado = a.horometro_estimado,
                        horometro_mantenimiento = a.horometro_mantenimiento,
                        horometro_final = a.horometro_final,
                        resultado_muestreo = a.resultado_muestreo,
                        emp = a.emp,
                        // 2024-07-08: Debido a que en la clase o mejor dicho en C# no esposible tener
                        // datos tipo DateTime como null, se procede a modificar el dato.
                        FechaInsert = new DateTime(1900, 01, 01),
                        // 2024-07-09: Para no crear una clase para este metodo se aprovecha uno ya creado pero
                        // se inhabilitan el campo Obra, el cual se calcula realmente en otro metodo.
                        Obra = "NoAplica",
                        // 2024-06-21: Se valida si hay registros en la tabla indicada.
                        Estado = b == null ? "NoAplica" : "Aplica"
                    }

Aqui podemos notar algo, dicho codigo tardar 12.727 segundos en ejecutarse, lo cual nos parece un tiempo algo para una consulta de este tipo.
Con el animo de salir de dudas, quitamos el LEFT JOIN del codigo LINQ para validar como funciona, quedando de esta manera el codigo en LINQPad 7:
from a in GeneMttoPrev
                    // 2024-07-09: Join entre dos tablas (tabla a y tabla b1).
                    join b1 in LlanHistoria on
                            a.equipo
                        equals
                            b1.equipo
                        into GrupoB
                    // 2024-07-09: Esto lo hago para que que sean LEFT JOIN.
                    //from b in GrupoB.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new 
                    {
                        Registro = a.Registro,
                        equipo = a.equipo,
                        bodega = a.bodega,
                        codigo_mantenimiento = a.codigo_mantenimiento,
                        ciclo = a.ciclo,
                        frecuencia_Mantenimiento = a.frecuencia_Mantenimiento,
                        unidad_frecuencia = a.unidad_frecuencia,
                        fecha_estimada = a.fecha_estimada,
                        fecha_mantenimiento = a.fecha_mantenimiento,
                        horometro_estimado = a.horometro_estimado,
                        horometro_mantenimiento = a.horometro_mantenimiento,
                        horometro_final = a.horometro_final,
                        resultado_muestreo = a.resultado_muestreo,
                        emp = a.emp,
                        // 2024-07-08: Debido a que en la clase o mejor dicho en C# no esposible tener
                        // datos tipo DateTime como null, se procede a modificar el dato.
                        FechaInsert = new DateTime(1900, 01, 01),
                        // 2024-07-09: Para no crear una clase para este metodo se aprovecha uno ya creado pero
                        // se inhabilitan el campo Obra, el cual se calcula realmente en otro metodo.
                        Obra = "NoAplica",
                        // 2024-06-21: Se valida si hay registros en la tabla indicada.
                        //Estado = b == null ? "NoAplica" : "Aplica"
                    }

Este codigo se ejecuto en 0.596 segundos identificando una gran diferencia entre ambos.
Hasta el momento, esta es la forma que conocemos para ejecutar LEFT JOIN pero debido a las dificultades actuales, vemos que seria necesario tener otras alternativas que nos ayuden a obtener los resultados deseados.
Agradecemos su ayuda para poder avanzar en nuestro proyecto.

Probaste la consulta SQL para ver cuando demora, porque parece que es un tema de base de datos y no de linq

El punto de mi comentario anterior es que, si pruebas el SQL generado directamente en la base de datos y te sigue dando un tiempo significativo, lo que tienes que atacar es la base datos ya sea evaluar si tus índices están bien, si existe una relación, etc. Porque seguramente tu tema no pasa por Linq. Cuántos registros tiene la tabla GeneMttoPrev y la LlanHistoria  ???

Hola Yussef, la tabla GeneMttoPrev tiene 60362 registros y la tabla LlanHistoria tiene  191944 registros. La falla ya la identificamos, es un problema que teniamos al hacer el join, ya que en la tabla LlanHistoria existen muchos registros que cumplen con el join de GeneMttoPrev. Por ejemplo tengo un caso dondo a un registro de la tabla GeneMttoPrev le corresponden 565 registros, eso quiere decir que genera 565 filas. Ya eso nos permite hacernos una idea del porque la consulta tarda considerablemente en ejecutarse. Ya con esto haremos las correcciones que permiten dar solucion de raiz. Gracias.

Saludos
En el primer segmento de código te hago las siguientes sugerencias:
[HttpGet("/Llantas/Mantenimientos/Equipos/Revisar", Name = "GetLlantasMantenimientosEquiposRevisar")]
public List<TemGeneMttoPrevObras> GetLlantasMantenimientosEquiposRevisar()
{
    try
    {
        // Todo el código anterior
                select new TemGeneMttoPrevObras
                {
                    // Todo el código anterior
                    // 2024-07-08: Debido a que en la clase o mejor dicho en C# no esposible tener
                    // datos tipo DateTime como null, se procede a modificar el dato.
                    FechaInsert = new DateTime(1900, 01, 01),
                    // 2024-07-09: Para no crear una clase para este metodo se aprovecha uno ya creado pero
                    // se inhabilitan el campo Obra, el cual se calcula realmente en otro metodo.
                    Obra = "NoAplica",
                    // 2024-06-21: Se valida si hay registros en la tabla indicada.
                    Estado = b == null ? "NoAplica" : "Aplica"
                };
        return q.ToList();
    } catch (Exception) {
        return TemGeneMttoPrevObrasExcepcion;
    }
}

Te sugiero probar en lugar del
from b in GrupoB.DefaultIfEmpty()

quitarlo; y en el new TemGeneMttoPrevObras que tu asignación de
Estado = b == null ? "NoAplica" : "Aplica"

lo cambies a
Estado = context.LlanHistoria.where(w => w.equipo==a.equipo).any() ? "Aplica" : "NoAplica"

lo anterior si de b no usas valor alguno para ser asignado. Adicionalmente, ¿la relación es 1 a 1? De lo contrario con cualquier coincidencia desde luego devolverá Aplica.
Otra opción es realizar lo siguiente (ojo con al relación entre GeneMttoPrev y LlanHistoria  como está definida) es usar:
public List<TemGeneMttoPrevObras> GetLlantasMantenimientosEquiposRevisar()
{
    try
        {
        var q = (from a in context.GeneMttoPrev
                select new {
                    a,
                    b = context.LlanHistoria.where(w => w.equipo == a.equipo).FirstOrDefault()
                })
                .Select(s => new TemGeneMttoPrevObras
                {
                    Registro = s.a.Registro,
                    equipo = s.a.equipo,
                    bodega = s.a.bodega,
                    codigo_mantenimiento = s.a.codigo_mantenimiento,
                    ciclo = s.a.ciclo,
                    frecuencia_Mantenimiento = s.a.frecuencia_Mantenimiento,
                    unidad_frecuencia = s.a.unidad_frecuencia,
                    fecha_estimada = s.a.fecha_estimada,
                    fecha_mantenimiento = s.a.fecha_mantenimiento,
                    horometro_estimado = s.a.horometro_estimado,
                    horometro_mantenimiento = s.a.horometro_mantenimiento,
                    horometro_final = s.a.horometro_final,
                    resultado_muestreo = s.a.resultado_muestreo,
                    emp = s.a.emp,
                    // 2024-07-08: Debido a que en la clase o mejor dicho en C# no esposible tener
                    // datos tipo DateTime como null, se procede a modificar el dato.
                    FechaInsert = new DateTime(1900, 01, 01),
                    // 2024-07-09: Para no crear una clase para este metodo se aprovecha uno ya creado pero
                    // se inhabilitan el campo Obra, el cual se calcula realmente en otro metodo.
                    Obra = "NoAplica",
                    // 2024-06-21: Se valida si hay registros en la tabla indicada.
                    Estado = s.b == null ? "NoAplica" : "Aplica"
                };
        return q.ToList();
    } catch (Exception) {
        return TemGeneMttoPrevObrasExcepcion;
    }
}


Si previo al .Select(s => new TemGeneMttoPrevObras ... te genera error; modifícalo para que quede de la siguiente forma .AsEnumerable().ToList().Select(s => new TemGeneMttoPrevObras ...

En relación al comentario que tienes
De tu comentario en el código
// 2024-07-08: Debido a que en la clase o mejor dicho en C# no esposible tener
// datos tipo DateTime como null, se procede a modificar el dato

A salvedad sea un malentendido o error en la documentación/redacción
class TemGeneMttoPrevObras {
    // Puede ser declarada así
    public DateTime? FechaInsert { get; set; }
    // o así
    public Nullable<DateTime> FechaInsert { get; set; }
}

En cuanto a la demora en realizarse
Revisa que la columna equipo de las tablas que intervienen en la consulta en ambas esté indexado o por lo menos en la que sea catálogo lo esté (en caso de ser catálogo debiera ser PK).
Lo "idóneo" sería (a mi juicio no soy DBA o similar) que en una fuese PK y en otra FK...; no "profundizo" más par no enredarte y por lo que desconozco de tu esquema.

RobertoLeOr muchas gracias por responder. Lastimosamente intentando la primera recomedacion (Estado = context.LlanHistoria.where(w => w.equipo==a.equipo).any() ? "Aplica" : "NoAplica"), no funciono, inclusive luego de 120 segundos, aun no logre respuesta de la consulta en utilizando LINQPad 7. Agradecemos la observacion con respecto a las fechas, ya que no sabiamos que podian ser null, ya con este consejo, realizaremos los ajuestes.
